# bq24171 battery charger does not charge

Tags: battery-charging, charger, lipo

I want to make a 2S LiPo battery charger. I used the bq24171 chip from TI and followed the datasheet. All the conditions to enable charging seem to be ok but there is no actual charging (no output voltage).
I can provide the board and schematic (in eagle). 
[image: ChargerSchematic]